# Android BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, bootcompleted

I have a question concerning the BOOT_COMPLETED event.
I need a service to be running at all time (done via AlarmManager) but I wonder if I have to start the service manually the first time the application is installed as the BOOT_COMPLETED event is sent only after the device is restarted. How is this commonly handled, it seems like no one is having this problem, am I getting something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the user should be the one deciding on if the service is running or not when its first installed and not you, so yes it should be started manually when they launch the app for the first time

Comment: Well the user decides if the service should be running but he does so by clicking an button which can be clicked later on several more times, it's somehow like the follow button on twitter. If I have to start it manually the first time is there a best practise to do so?

Comment: Just start it when the app starts